# Write a proxy class in C++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ wrapper class which encapsulates some hardware extraction as:

```
class DeviceWrapper
{
private:
    PhysicalDevice mDevice;
};
```

There are various classes that access the device and most of them accept the underlying device as their first parameter, like so:

```
void someFunc(PhysicalDevice & device);
```

So I currently have the following getter method in my wrapper class:

```
PhysicalDevice & DeviceWrapper::getPhysicalDevice()
{
    return mDevice;
}
```

And I use it like this: `someFunc(myWrapper.getPhysicalDevice());`

However, this looks a bit cumbersome. Is there a way to define some sort of operator which returns the reference to this device and then I can basically use the reference to the wrapper class wherever the reference to the `PhyscialDevice` is needed.

Comment: there is a way, but implicit conversion should be used with care, because it can lead to confusing errors, when the conversion is not expected, though in this case it seems to be more than reasonable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 common ways of expressing this:

1. provide an implicit conversion:

```
class DeviceWrapper
{
    operator PhysicalDevice&() { return mDevice; }
private:
    PhysicalDevice mDevice;
};
```

2. re-implement the function as a method (for reasons mentioned in another answer, I would favour this approach):

```
class DeviceWrapper
{
    auto someFunc() { return ::somefunc(mDevice); }

private:
    PhysicalDevice mDevice;
};
```

Comment: But the explicit conversion will require a `static_cast<PhysicalDevice&>(myWrapper)`, which isn't any terser than `myWrapper.getPhysicalDevice()`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, exactly!

```
class DeviceWrapper
{
    // ...
public:
    operator PhysicalDevice &() {
        return mDevice;
    }
};
```

And you're done: a `DeviceWrapper` can now be converted implicitly to a reference to its `PhysicalDevice`, for example in function calls expecting a `PhysicalDevice &`.

Comment: What's the advantage of doing this over simply inheriting from PhysicalDevice?

Comment: Thanks as well! I would upvote but my points will not let me!

Answer (score 2):

If you have full control over the API, **I would advise against** the cast operator and would suggest blocking any kind of access to the underlying device object.

**Why?** Because APIs should be **easy to use** but **hard to misuse**. If you allow users to access the underlying object both directly and through the proxy, it might result in inconsistent run-time states.

Instead rather wrap all the API methods using your proxy, thus managing the state and keeping it consistent:

```
class DeviceWrapper
{
public:
    void someFunc1(PhysicalDevice & device) { ::someFunc1(mDevice); }
    void someFunc2(PhysicalDevice & device) { ::someFunc2(mDevice); }

private:
    PhysicalDevice mDevice;
};
```

Comment: This is a good point as well. I managed to separate everything with use of friend classes.